# Adding a new select to a page using innerHTML causes previously added select elements to lose any value the user has selected from the dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, select, innerhtml

I have encountered a strange issue with a page that adds a series of dropdowns to a page using Javascript DOM manipulation (`innerHTML`).

I am adding a new dropdown upon button click with code equivalent to this:

```
  html = `<select class="selector">
            <option value="">No value selected</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
          </select>`;
  containerDOMElement.innerHTML += html;
```

When a new dropdown is added to the page in this manner, I am seeing any other selects where a selection had been made by the user, getting their values cleared.

I have reproduced the issue in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexbfree/8ykjpvau/).

To see the problem, manually select option B from the first and third dropdowns once the page has loaded.
Now press "add another" and notice that the first and third dropdowns have lost their selection.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can get the dropdowns to keep their value when a new one is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

`containerDOMElement.innerHTML += html;`

Has the same functionality as this line:

`containerDOMElement.innerHTML = containerDOMElement.innerHTML + html;`

Looking at it differently you can see that the entire HTML is being rebuilt, thus losing the currently selected options.

---

Instead, to append HTML we can use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). In your case:

`containerEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);`

---

Here's a working version of your JSFiddle:

```js
let existing_options = [
    "A","B","C"
];

let containerEl = document.getElementById("container");

let count = 0;

function addSelect(preselectOptionB=false) {
    html = `<select class="selector" name=${count}><option value="">No value selected</option>`;
    existing_options.forEach(function (dataValue,index)
    {
        html += `<option value=${dataValue} ${(preselectOptionB && dataValue=="B") ? 'selected="selected"' : ""}>${dataValue}</option>`;
    });
    html += `</select><br/>`;
    
    count++;
    containerEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}

function addNewSelectWithNoValue() {
    addSelect(false);
}

let button = document.getElementById("addbutton");
button.addEventListener('click', addNewSelectWithNoValue);

// add four initial ones.
addSelect();
addSelect(true);
addSelect();
addSelect(true);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<hr/>
<button id="addbutton">Add another</button>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you @Gary. What this must mean, which I had not realised, is that retrieving `.innerHTML` on a DOM node  does not return the full current state of that node and its children on the page. I guess it must be the node contents as initially rendered or something like that. Anyway thanks for helping me understand what was going on.